# MongoDB C# Linq Dynamic Querying Nullable Date

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I want to build a query to fetch the records based on the transaction date which is a non-nullable field. If I pass `fromDate` and `toDate` in where condition it should fetch records between the dates and if I'm not passing the values (passing `null`) need to fetch all the records. If I use the below code it is fetching only when I pass the `fromDate` and `toDate` values and if values are not passed data not fetching.

Is there an option to fetch the records if I pass null values to date?

```
public IQueryable<WithdrawalVM> GetWithDrawalTransactions(DateTime? fromDate, DateTime? toDate, decimal? amountFrom, decimal? amountTo)
        {
                return (from tx in _transactionRepository.Queryable()
                        join ar in _accountRepository.Queryable()
                        on tx.AccountId equals ar.Id
                        where tx.TransactionDate >= fromDate && tx.TransactionDate <= toDate
                        select new WithdrawalVM
                        {
                            
                        }).OrderByDescending(x => x.TransactionDate).AsQueryable();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use null coalescing, I think this should work

```cs
where tx.TransactionDate >= fromDate ?? DateTime.MinValue && tx.TransactionDate <= toDate ?? DateTime.MaxValue
```

alternately break up the statement.

```cs
var query = (from tx in _transactionRepository.Queryable()
                        join ar in _accountRepository.Queryable()
                        on tx.AccountId equals ar.Id);

if(fromDate.HasValue)
{
    query = query.Where(tx => tx.TransactionDate >= fromDate);
}

if(toDate.HasValue)
{
    query = query.Where(tx => tx.TransactionDate <= toDate);
}

return query.Select(tx => WithdrawalVM
                        {
                            
                        }).OrderByDescending(x => x.TransactionDate).AsQueryable();
```